# Why does CSS position absolute work with margin?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I thought adding `margin`  to an element in `position: absolute`  does not work.

In the following snippet,  `#child2`in  `#parent2` is in `position: absolute` and yet adding  `margin: 10px` seems to work as `#child2` seems to be in alignment with `#child1`, which does not have `position: absolute`

Why is this happening or what am I getting wrong about  `margin` and  `position: absolute` of elements ?

```css
#root{
  display:flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
#parent1{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
#child1{
  background:hotpink;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#parent2{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
#child2{
  background:cyan;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;   /* <-- Why does margin work here */
}
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div id="parent1">  
    <div id="child1">no absolute</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="parent2">
    <div id="child2">absolute</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What was your expected behavior? Margin should always work regardless of the position.

Comment: @ITgoldman even with top/left you will get a similar output